# OSX Hungarian Lang, no hashmark(#) no star(*) characters

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I cannont descibe this any better then show you this video I recorded. Showing keyboad viewer.

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FESogSDuPNA)

I am looking for a way to put hashmark and star to some alternate place without changing the language.

Answer (score 0):

I found the so-called 'ukelele' app to create custom layouts.
Maybe this could help.
http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10370274-263.html

Comment: This seems like a good comment, but as an answer it does not answer much. Can you expand this?

Comment: Isnt there an app for this? :D